# NodeJS communicating with other NodeJS instances and managing minecraft server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, networking

I was wondering how would I communicate with another NodeJS instance? For instance I have one NodeJS instance that is a chat room, how would I get the chat and all people connected to the chat from another NodeJS instance. 
Secondly I was also wondering is it possible to manage Minecraft servers using NodeJS so for example create a directory copy all the necessary files then start the server with x amount of ram and be able to receive output of the server and send console commands.

Comment: Socket.IO is probably a good start if you want to implement networked server communication between two or more NodeJS instances. And the further questions are also possible, but this is not something SO will give you an answe to - google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options, Socket.io, Rest, Soap, TCP/IP or even low-level protocols. Really depends on what is supported by Chat node. If you are the owner of both nodes, then I would suggest to use [Socket.io](http://socket.io/), it is more real time and supports push-based communication, otherwise you will have to periodically hit REST or SOAP API of remote node.

As far as NodeJS is concerned it can execute shell commands for [example](https://dzone.com/articles/execute-unix-command-nodejs). From there it is upto Minecraft what it offers and adheres to.